# Direct spring framework logging for separate log file

Tags: spring, log4j

I am using log4j in springframework based application. I need to direct log messages generated by spring framework to app.log file and business logic related logs for business.log file.
My log4j.property file is like following.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, appLogger, bizLogger

log4j.appender.appLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appLogger.File=./logs/app.log
log4j.appender.appLogger.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.appLogger.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.appLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c] %p - %m%n

log4j.appender.bizLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bizLogger.File=./logs/biz.log
log4j.appender.bizLogger.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.bizLogger.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.bizLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bizLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c] %p - %m%n
```

I am getting the bizLogger in code and use it for logging. But both files contain both log statements. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to define logs per package. Check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297686/log4j-package-specific-logging

Answer (score 2):

As Mani's comment suggests, you need to define logs per package.

So, if your spring framework packages begin with `org.springframework` and your business logic packages begin with `com.myapp`, then you can add the following lines to your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG,appLogger
log4j.logger.com.myapp=DEBUG,bizLogger
```

Of course, set the threshold (`DEBUG`, `INFO`, etc.) to your preference.  You may also wish to set `additivity` to false:

```
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
log4j.additivity.com.myapp=false
```