# In log4j fileappender not appending any logs in file

Tags: java, log4j, fileappender

I am using log4j for webapplication. I had tried a java example of log4j that makes different log files according to package. But when I applied it to webApplication the file is generating but it is blank. No output is displaying in file. Below is the code.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA

log4j.appender.pkg1Appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.pkg1Appender.File=E://pkg1.log

log4j.appender.pkg2Appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.pkg2Appender.File=E://pkg2.log

# ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.logger.pkg1=,pkg1Appender
log4j.logger.pkg2=,pkg2Appender
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the package specific appenders to the root logger line.

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, pkg1Appender, pkg2Appender

See the answer to this question here: [log4j: package-specific logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297686/log4j-package-specific-logging)

Comment: I also tried it. It will print all logs into it not package specific.

Comment: My project has a central method name printout() that I had used all over my project. Now I want to apply log4j in application. I made a static variable of logger and using it in printout() method. So, I never get from which package logger is printing. I think it is reason that my appender file is blank? Do you have any alternative so that I dnt have to change all source file to implement logger.

Comment: You can try using aop,if that is feasible for you

Comment: thanks but i have just went through it once in video tutorial and know that it will be used in spring. Should I use it without spring? and project uses jdk 5.

Comment: This is a hack - 
Make your printout method to accept a logger defined in individual classes to print the message instead of using a central logger.

Comment: Kiran there are hundreds of file in existing project I can't change all files for logging. I am thinking if my url change jsp package dynamically according to that should I get logs in different file? using this central logger concept is thi possible? I read in one thread of stackoverflow that once logger is initialized it cannot change file dynamically. thats why I am confused a bit.