# Partial Logging in Database using log4j

Tags: java, mysql, logging, log4j

We are using quartz job in our application. How can I log only logs of these Job Classes and not of all applications.

I am using JDBCAppender of log4j but it inserts all logs in database.

Can we add multiple log4j.xml e.g log4j.xml and log4j_job.xml configuration files and configure these classes to use that log4j_job.xml ?

Comment: check the following thread. it provides a solutions if you are using specific packages for you jobs classes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297686/log4j-package-specific-logging

Comment: @akshayapandey  My all job classes are in same package but that package contains many other classes too